# Permission denied when trying to list /var/root/Library from Terminal

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

In Terminal when I tried to go to or list that folder, I got the Permission denied message.  In Finder there is a Library folder in Sys volume.  Are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

type "sudo -s" in terminal to have administrator privilege in your terminal session

And "Library" in sys volume is another folder from... another volume :)